# Font and color changing to default after exporting report to Excel from SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2, msbi

I have a report which is rendering fine in my local VS and Reports Server but, when I export the report to `EXCEL` and opened it, the font of certain areas of the report are changing back to the default.

The report is supposed to look like:

[image]

But it is turning to the following when exported to `Excel`:

[image]

Can someone help with this please? Thank you.

Comment: When you export it into excel from bids does it change the font also or remains the same?

Comment: Sorry I didn’t get u.bids?